# Magento error after migration "Cannot send headers, Headers already sent in"

Tags: magento, zend-framework, header, migration, cpanel

I am getting the following error (after I moved magento from once server to another)

```
a:5:{i:0;s:110:
"Cannot send headers; headers already sent in /home/user/public_html/lib/Varien/Event/Collection.php, line 1";
i:1;s:1013:"
#0 /home/user/public_html/lib/Zend/Controller/Response/Abstract.php(114): Zend_Controller_Response_Abstract->canSendHeaders(true)
#1 /home/user/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(1265): Zend_Controller_Response_Abstract->setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/html; char...')
#2 /home/user/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(80): Mage_Core_Model_App->getResponse()
#3 /home/user/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(202): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->getResponse()
#4 /home/user/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(172): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#5 /home/user/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(365): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
#6 /home/user/public_html/app/Mage.php(684): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#7 /home/user/public_html/index.php(83): Mage::run('', 'store')
#8 {main}
";s:3:"url";s:1:"/";s:11:"script_name";s:10:"/index.php";s:4:"skin";s:5:"dutch";}
```

Comment: I edited Zend_Controller_Response_Abstract->canSendHeaders(true)
to 
Zend_Controller_Response_Abstract->canSendHeaders(false)

and now i can see website comes back.
is that something will be fine?

Comment: After setting canSendHeaders(false) All menu pages says 404

Answer (score 0):

I have solved my issue some other  way.
This was magento 1.9.1 & i update it to 1.9.2.2, site came back as normal but some blocks were not showing on front page. I followed this https://magentary.com/kb/cms-pages-transactional-emails-broken-after-supee-6788-patch/
 and the issue almost resolved
Thanks.